# Comparar cadenas en c#

Tags: c#

Como puedo comparar cadenas en c#? tengo un archivo en mysql es un catalogo de contabilidad, el campo de código es alfanumérico y necesito hacer un reporte que va de tal cuenta a tal otra

```
if (item.co01.Substring(0, largo1) >= cta1.Trim() && item.co01.Substring(0, largo2) <= cta2.Trim())
{
   ....
}
```

El error que me da es que el operador `>=` no se puede aplicar a `string`, no puedo convertir los códigos contables a `int` o `decimal` porque tienen letras algunos, `cta1` es la cuenta menor y `cta2` la cuenta mayor del intervalo a listar.
Alguien me puede decir como hacer esto?

Comment: Probablemente deberías explicar bajo que criterios una codigo es mayor que otro. Es solo comparando la parte numérica? Es relevante la parte alfabética?. Pon un par de ejemplos de los formatos y como deben compararse.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh el problema es que puede ser un rango, por ejemplo la cta1 = "1000001' y cta2 = "210001002A"  entre estos dos códigos de cuenta pueden haber 100 o mas, igual podrían haber solo dos.  Y si el la parte alfabética puede tener relevancia, puede haber cuentas A,B,C, etc. y solo queremos que el rango llegue a la primera.

Comment: Con el ejemplo que pones, no termino de entender el criterio que teneis definido para la nomenclatura de las cuentas. Sin un criterio claro, veo complicado que podais comparar las cuentas.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar la funcion `String.Compare` de `c#` te devuelve un valor entero negativo si la primera cadena es menor a la segunda o es null, en caso contrario valor positivo, si son iguales el valor es `0` [Comparación de cadenas en .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/comparing)

Ejemplo:

```
if (String.Compare(item.co01.Substring(0, largo1), cta1.Trim())>=0 && String.Compare(item.co01.Substring(0, largo2), cta2.Trim())<=0) { .... }
```